# How to terminate run() when it is called directly

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```java
public class Fiji{

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        MyThread a = new MyThread();
        a.start();
        a.run();
    }
    
    public class MyThread extends Thread {
    
        public void run() {
            // terminate if run is called directly
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above the `MyThread a` is called in two different ways. Once via `start()` and once directly by calling `run()`. By calling `run()` directly no new thread is created. So the program flow is still serialized.

How can I detect (in my `run()` method) if it is being called directly?

Comment: Maybe by checking if Main Thread is executing this method then terminating it. But why do you need it though.

Comment: Although you're not encouraged to override `Thread` directly (instead, creating an instance of `Runnable` and passing it to an instance of `Thread`), you might set the name of the thread, then look at the name of the current running thread

Comment: @Typhon I want to get familiar with the concept of Threads. How can I check if the main Thread has executed `a.run()`?

Comment: @GentleSama Arguably, you don't or shouldn't.  It's not the `run` methods responsibility to do this, it's responsibility is to execute the functionality when it's called

Comment: *How can I detect (in my `run()` method) if it is being called directly?*  OK, ***why***?  I'll often run N parallel threads by creates ***N-1*** separate threads and then call `run()` directly from the main thread.  Then when that call to `run()` returns `join()` the other ***N-1*** threads.  That saves the overhead of one thread creation and call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you're not encouraged to extent from `Thread` directly, but instead, create a new instance of `Runnable` and pass it to an instance of `Thread`, however, in your particular case, you could compare the `currentThread` to the instance of `MyThread`, for example...

```
static public class MyThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (Thread.currentThread() == this) {
            System.out.println("You're all mine");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Does not belong to me");
        }
    }
    
}
```

However, I would argue that you're trying to fix the problem in the wrong place, it's not the responsibility of your `run` method to be making this kind of check, it's the responsibility of the calling code to ensure it's doing the right thing in the first place (and they're are probably, arguably, occasions when calling `run` directly is the desired workflow).

The main problem with trying to do what you're doing is you can't tell the caller they've done the wrong thing, without throwing a runtime exception.

Comment: Could you not wait like 3 more minutes and let me finish my answer :@,  haha I am kidding .good explanation (+1)

Comment: @Typhon  I finally beat someone for a change

Answer (score 0):

This is more secure, prevents normal access from outside to run(), and lets the class alone handle the threading stuff.

```
package stackoverflow.mythread;

public class MyThread {

    public static void main(final String[] arg) {
        final BetterMyThread a = new BetterMyThread();
        a.start();
        a.run(); // compilation error
    }

}
```

and

```
package stackoverflow.mythread;

public class BetterMyThread { // dont have

    private Thread myLocalThread; // access this for other thread-realted tasks

    public void start() {
        myLocalThread = new Thread(() -> run());
        myLocalThread.start();
    }

    private void run() { // cannot be called directly from outside the class with normal code. Reflection of bytecode manipulation would be needed
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

and

```
package stackoverflow.mythread;

public class BetterMyThread2 {

    private final Thread myLocalThread = new Thread(() -> run());

    public void start() {
        myLocalThread.start();
    }

    private void run() { // cannot be called directly from outside the class with normal code. Reflection of bytecode manipulation would be needed
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

// **UPDATE:**

using an explicit anonymous class instead of lambda.
I renamed `BetterMyThread3.run()` to `BetterMyThread3.runLocal()` to avoid name shadowing conflict inside the Runnable.run().

```
package stackoverflow.mythread;

public class BetterMyThread3 {

    private final Thread myLocalThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            runLocal(); // in pure java this would not work; javac generates a synthetic accessor method
        }
    });

    public void start() {
        myLocalThread.start();
    }

    private void runLocal() { // cannot be called directly from outside the class with normal code. Reflection of bytecode manipulation would be needed
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I could also have written

```
package stackoverflow.mythread;

public class BetterMyThread4 {

    private final Thread myLocalThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            BetterMyThread4.this.run(); // in pure java this would not work; javac generates a synthetic accessor method
        }
    });

    public void start() {
        myLocalThread.start();
    }

    private void run() { // cannot be called directly from outside the class with normal code. Reflection of bytecode manipulation would be needed
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

but this is not as clean as it could / should be.

Comment: How does `() -> run()` work? Is my understanding correct, that it tells `new Thread()` to override `public void run()` with our local private run?

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify what's going on there. `()->run()` is called a lambda expression, i.e. a classless expression that can be used like this with interfaces/abstract classes where only one method is unimplemented. In contrast to the lambda I gave you the 'classical' Java approach by implementing an anonymous class (Runnable).

Comment: I see. So whenever there's one method that has to be implemented I could use `() -> method()`. This would tell my class that the to be overridden method is being implemented with `method()`. Correct?

Comment: So it is NOT overriding anything in our class BetterMyThreadX, but overriding the (unseen and unwritten) Runnable's run() method. As you see in my Example (BetterMyThread3) the naming from `BetterMyThread3.run()` and the anonymous' `Runnable.run()` would collide, hence I renamed our `BetterMyThread3.run()` to `BetterMyThread3.runLocal()`. In `BetterMyThread4` you see that I leave that collision (both methods are called `run()` but by very explicitly addressing the method I can call the right one.

Comment: @GentleSama Not quite. The `() ->` part is the part that "overrides" that one abstract method. What happens after the `->` is just normal code. You could also write `() -> System.out.println("Hello World");` or even have multiple lines like so: `()-> { System.out.println("X"); System.out.println("Y"); /*and any other method call*/ }`. You can also pass parameters (if the abstract method requires/provides it, which runnable does not):  `(e) -> System.out.println(e);`. Check out tutorials: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp

Comment: Ok, I see how the lambda expression is used. One last Question remains. You've written `in pure java this would not work; ...`. Could you clarify what you mean by "would not work", because if I run the code it is compiled and executed. What about it "would not work"? - Do you mean if the name of your private method remains `run()` it would not work?

Comment: Yes. If you used pure javac compilation without letting javac generate *synthetic accessor methods* the code could not compile. Most IDEs allow creation of SAMs, so this is not a 'problem'. If you use Eclipse, the compiler warning/error setting is called "Access to a non-accessible member of an enclosing type". Check out Synthetic Accessor Methods on google for more.

Comment: I will do some studying on this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also use `new Thread(this::run)` instead of  `new Thread(() -> run())`. It would be a good move to also use a different name like `runLocal` in that case. Besides that, there’s no such thing as “pure java”. The synthetic accessor method is a bytecode artifact irrelevant to the language. And, well, since JDK 11, it does not exist anymore as the bytecode format has been adapted to make them unnecessary.